# how to resolve the infinite nesting of interactive POMDP

Tags: probability-distributions, markov-chains, game-theory

I am reading papers about I-POMDP. I cant understand the finitely nested I-POMDPs given in these papers.

The belief update of the algorithm has a problem that agents' belief updates mutually depend on each others. For instance, the update functions for a system containing agent i and agent j are list as follows.
\begin{equation}
b_i^t(is_i^t) = \tau_{m_j^{t-1}} (b_i^{t-1}(is_i^{t-1});o_i^t,a_i^{t-1}) = \beta \sum_{is_i^{t-1} \vert \hat{\theta}_j^{t-1} = \hat{\theta}_j^t} {b_i^{t-1}(is_i^{t-1}) \sum_{a_j^{t-1}}{P(a_j^{t-1}\vert m_j^{t-1})P(o_i^t \vert s^t,a^{t-1})P(s^t \vert a^{t-1},s^{t-1})\sum_{o_j^t}{\delta_K(\tau_{m_i^{t-1}}(b_j^{t-1} ; o_j^t , a_j^{t-1})-b_j^t) P(o_j^t \vert s^t , a^{t-1})}}}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
b_j^t(is_j^t) = \tau_{m_i^{t-1}} (b_j^{t-1}(is_j^{t-1});o_j^t,a_j^{t-1}) = \beta \sum_{is_j^{t-1} \vert \hat{\theta}_i^{t-1} = \hat{\theta}_i^t} {b_j^{t-1}(is_j^{t-1}) \sum_{a_i^{t-1}}{P(a_i^{t-1}\vert m_i^{t-1})P(o_j^t \vert s^t,a^{t-1})P(s^t \vert a^{t-1},s^{t-1})\sum_{o_i^t}{\delta_K(\tau_{m_j^{t-1}}(b_i^{t-1} ; o_i^t , a_i^{t-1})-b_i^t) P(o_i^t \vert s^t , a^{t-1})}}}
\end{equation}
As you can see above, calculation of $\tau_{m_j^{t-1}} (b_i^{t-1}(is_i^{t-1});o_i^t,a_i^{t-1})$ and $\tau_{m_i^{t-1}} (b_j^{t-1}(is_j^{t-1});o_j^t,a_j^{t-1})$ depend on the outcome of each other.

The papers discussing this topic give a solution called finitely nested I-POMDPs. The solution update the belief with subintentional model first for level 0. The belief update is as follows.
\begin{equation}
b_{i,0}^t(is_{i,0}^t) = b^t_{i,0}(s^t) = \beta \sum_{is_i^{t-1} \vert \hat{\theta}_j^{t-1} = \hat{\theta}_j^t} {b_{i,0}^{t-1}(is_{i,0}^{t-1}) \sum_{a_j^{t-1}}{P(a_j^{t-1}\vert m_j^{t-1})P(o_i^t \vert s^t,a^{t-1})P(s^t \vert a^{t-1},s^{t-1})\sum_{o_j^t}{\delta_K(\text{APPEND}(h_j^{t-1},o_j^t),h_j^t) P(o_j^t \vert s^t , a^{t-1})}}}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
b_{j,0}^t(is_{j,0}^t) = b^t_{j,0}(s^t) = \beta \sum_{is_j^{t-1} \vert \hat{\theta}_i^{t-1} = \hat{\theta}_i^t} {b_{j,0}^{t-1}(is_{j,0}^{t-1}) \sum_{a_i^{t-1}}{P(a_i^{t-1}\vert m_i^{t-1})P(o_j^t \vert s^t,a^{t-1})P(s^t \vert a^{t-1},s^{t-1})\sum_{o_i^t}{\delta_K(\text{APPEND}(h_i^{t-1},o_i^t),h_i^t) P(o_i^t \vert s^t , a^{t-1})}}}
\end{equation}
Seemingly, the two update functions dont depend on each other now. But how could I do for level 1? I know I should solve the following updates for level 1.
\begin{equation}
b_{i,1}^t(is_{i,1}^t) = b_{i,1}(s^t, \langle b_{j,0}^t , \hat{m}_j^t \rangle)
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
b_{j,1}^t(is_{j,1}^t) = b_{j,1}(s^t, \langle b_{i,0}^t , \hat{m}_i^t \rangle)
\end{equation}
How to do the update on level 1 to avoid mututal dependence? I can't understand the solution from the papers. Thanks for any hints.

Comment: Wow, that's quite some unreadable notation! any chance you can simplify the notation so that it's easy to get to the real question (which is obscured by the notation here)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The seeming circular dependence of belief update of agent i and agent j can be better understood when you refer to section 6 of the paper.  There, the finitely nested IPOMDPs are introduced. One can see that agent i's beliefs nested down to level l are spanned over the physical states S and models of the agent j, M_{j,l-1}, i.e., models of j nested down to level l-1. So, for finitely nested IPOMDPs the belief update is recursive: agent i models agent j's belief update 
at level l-1, and j models i's belief update at level l-2, etc.  Recursion bottoms out at the "flat", 0-level POMDP belief update.

Hope this helps!

--Piotr